# specific sql query trouble

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble writing this Query. I have 2 tables, vote_table and click_table.  in the vote_table I have two fields, id and date.  the format of the date is "12/30/11 : 14:28:36".  in the click_table i have two fields, id and date.  the format of the date is "12.30.11".

The id's occur multiple times in both tables.  What i want to do is produce a result that contains 3 fields: id, votes, clicks.  the id column should have distinct id values, the votes column should have the total times that ID has the date 12/30/11% from the vote_table, and the clicks should have the total times that ID has the date 12.30.11 from the click table, so something like this:

```
ID | VOTES | CLICKS

001 | 24  |  50

002  |  30  |  45
```

Comment: is everyone on here so pretentious

Comment: @JonathanLeffler There was a bit of venom in that comment.  That seems a bit unnecessary.  This is a place that people come to get help who don't know any better.  Be decent or don't comment.

Comment: Probably not.  But you've not told us some important details about your table.  And using VARCHAR for date values is a serious problem.

Comment: The problem is that bad designs make it more-difficult to help people.

Comment: Rephrased: Why the inconsistency in the date formats? What is the underlying type of those fields?

Comment: it is varchar. i'm very new to sql so forgive my mistakes.  I'm just trying to get better and figure out how things are done

Comment: The trouble with using VARCHAR for date values is that you make it extremely difficult to do things like compare values which are stored in different formats.  If you use an appropriate DATE/TIME type, then the database stores the values in a consistent way and there are no issues such as 'the format in one column (or table) is mm/dd/yy and in another it is mm.dd.yy' and the system handles 4-digit years automatically (even if the result ends up being presented as a 2-digit year).  The comment about the formats was what suggested to me that you might be using VARCHAR.

Comment: right, but can't you just write a query that says where date = "12.30.11" or date LIKE "12/30/11%"

Comment: Yes, you can for a single date, but things get increasingly bad as you want to things like 'all dates in December' or 'for each date between 12th and 24th of the month' or the like.  Not using the DATE, DATETIME or TIMESTAMP types to store date/time values simply makes life harder for everyone - especially you.

Comment: For future reference, when asking a question about SQL, please include (sufficient of) the schema of the tables (table names, column names and types at minimum), and unique constraints or primary keys, and foreign keys where relevant.  (You avoided one of the most common mistakes, missing out the table names.  It is amazing how often those answering the question have to make up table names in order to answer it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the types of the 'date' columns are actually either DATE or DATETIME (rather than, say, VARCHAR), then the required operation is fairly straight-forward:

```
SELECT v.id, v.votes, c.clicks
  FROM (SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS votes
          FROM vote_table AS v1
         WHERE DATE(v1.`date`) = TIMESTAMP('2011-12-30')
         GROUP BY v1.id) AS v
  JOIN (SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS clicks
          FROM click_table AS c1
         WHERE DATE(c1.`date`) = TIMESTAMP('2011-12-30')
         GROUP BY c1.id) AS c
    ON v.id = c.id
 ORDER BY v.id;
```

Note that this only shows ID values for which there is at least one vote and at least one click on the given day.  If you need to see all the ID values which either voted or clicked or both, then you have to do more work.

If you have to normalize the dates because they are VARCHAR columns, the WHERE clauses become correspondingly more complex.

Comment: i get this error: Column 'id' cannot be null. I think a couple of the id fields are NULL though, is there a quick fix for that?

Comment: I've just added the missing GROUP BY clauses.  Make sure you have a primary key on each of your tables; make sure you have NOT NULL constraints on your columns.  Delete the rows 'WHERE id IS NULL' before altering your table to prevent repetitions of the problem.  Always include 'NOT NULL' constraints on every column unless you have a specific reason to allow nulls in that column.

Comment: i ran it and it ran successfully but didn't return anything.  Not sure if this matters but the id field is not primary and not unique.  there are multiple ids... so if id 001 voted 3 times today, there are going to be 3 rows that say 001, 2011-12-30.  I'm trying to count up all of those for each id in both tables.

Comment: The code actually should work, more or less, even with duplicate entries in the tables.  But, as written, it will probably only work if the types are DATE or DATETIME (or TIMESTAMP).  If they are VARCHAR, then you have to rewrite the conditions, and I'm feeling too lazy to do that for you.  You should have something to make each click and each vote unique - what was clicked on or voted on, and probably a timestamp to 1 second or finer accuracy.  I suspect that you got no data because the conversions failed for one or both of the sub-queries, leaving you comparing NULL with the date.

Comment: To isolate the problem, run the sub-queries in isolation and view the date that they generate - if any.  If they don't generate any, you'll need to twist the WHERE clause into shape suitable for your data.  When both sub-queries are working in isolation, you can combine them more or less as shown.

Comment: im not sure if this helps, but if i run the first sub-query without group by... i get NULL, 0.  if i run it with group by... i get no result